# Precompile error.. main runtime: panicked at 'Digest item must match that calculated,'

Tags: parachain, frontier, validator, evm, precompile

I was adding a new precompile function to my parachain,

then when I ran my parachain and invoked one of the precompile functions, I got this error from one of the polkadot validators:
`Relaychain Collation wasn't advertised to any validator`

and that validator went from connecting to 2 peers(the other validator and the parachain) to 1 peer(the other validator).

and this error showed up from my parachain collator:

```
ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Digest item must match that calculated.'

[Parachain] Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! 

runtime::storage: Corrupted state at [29, 186, 24, 76, 175, 197, 232, 114, 222, 94, 248, 240, 95, 69, 38, 7, 232, 157, 0, 204, 183, 181, 2, 22, 12, 248, 168, 34, 221, 252, 65, 168, 174, 167, 89, 124, 78, 203, 37, 115, 239, 230, 87, 126, 236, 129, 58, 120, 13, 109, 47, 202, 237, 47, 44, 205, 92, 29, 92, 134, 70, 132, 144, 242, 170, 254, 236, 139, 124, 177, 74, 245, 18, 205, 248, 199, 152, 1, 131, 163]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to build a new WASM again following the tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/connect-a-local-parachain/

```
./parachain-collator build-spec \
--disable-default-bootnode > rococo-local-parachain-plain.json \
&& ./parachain-collator build-spec --chain rococo-local-parachain-plain.json \
--raw --disable-default-bootnode > parachain-raw.json \
&& ./parachain-collator export-genesis-wasm \
--chain parachain-raw.json > para-wasm \
&& ./parachain-collator export-genesis-state \
--chain parachain-raw.json > para-genesis
```